# undefined reference using depthimage_to_laserscan

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, depthimage-to-laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to convert a Image taken by a Kinect into a LaserScan, but I have the following compile error when creating an instance of DepthImageToLaserScan:

```
undefined reference to `depthimage_to_laserscan::DepthImageToLaserScan::DepthImageToLaserScan()'
```

I found out that it is a linker issue, but I don't know how to fix it. I would really appreciate any help.

Code to create the instance of DepthImageToLaserScan:

```
depthimage_to_laserscan::DepthImageToLaserScan image_to_laser_converter_;
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/183070/undefined-reference-using-depthimage_to_laserscan/) by [HyEnd](https://answers.ros.org/users/18036/hyend/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2014-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you include the package depthimage_to_laserscan as build_dep, and run_dep in package.xml as well as in

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED roscpp depthimage_to_laserscan .... )
```

in your CMakeLists.txt ?

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HyEnd](https://answers.ros.org/users/18036/hyend/) on 2014-07-05**:
That was it, Thank you!